# Ember prepends application name in the script tag in production environment

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to build my application in production environment, which seems fine.
But as soon as I access the application, I get the following errors in the console:

**Error parsing 'integrity' attribute. The specified hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512'.**

The hash seems fine, the problem is that the integrity attributes is like:

`<script src="appname/path/assets/filename.js" integrity="appname/path/sha256...."></script>`

instead of:

`<script src="appname/path/assets/filename.js" integrity="sha256...."></script>`

I don't really know why is it adding the name and the path in the first place, or where or how it's configured.

I also added the type attribute, that also got prepended with **appname/path**

Can anyone please help me with the correct configuration for this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried configuring the root url ?

`config/environment.js`

```
if (environment === 'production') {
  ENV.rootURL = '/path/to/ember/app/';
}
```

Reference: https://cli.emberjs.com/release/basic-use/deploying/#configuringrooturl

Even have a look at this (Generation of SRI hashes for ember
):
https://cli.emberjs.com/release/advanced-use/asset-compilation/#subresourceintegrity

Comment: thank you for your response, but I have played around with the rootURL with no difference.